# Dynamically referencing object passed to a function

Tags: javascript, object

I have 'n' number of objects

```
obj1 = { 
   "foo":[],
   "bar":[]
}
obj2 = { 
   "foo":[1,2,3],
   "bar":['a','b','c']
}
```

…and so on.

Now let's say I want to pass obj1 or obj2 to a function to process the object as follows:

```
process_object('obj2');
```

how then does one accurately reference (for example)  obj2.bar[1]

```
function process_object(this_object_obj){
   console.log(this_object_obj.bar[1]); // should = b
}
```

Comment: [There's nothing JSON related in your code. You just have JavaScript.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Just call `process_json(obj2)` instead of `process_json('obj2')`

Comment: @lucifer63 thank you that was the answer I was looking for